# Linked list iteration running infinitely

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I implemented a linked list. And now I should sum each corresponding item of the two Linked Lists.

This is the implementation of the Linked list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=0, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            yield current.data
            current = current.next_node
    
    def add_last(self, node):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = node
            return

        current = self.head

        while current.next_node:
            current = current.next_node

        current.next_node = node
```

But when I sum items of each linked list, I am having an infinite loop and my linked list is not iterating

Here is the summing process

```
def two_sum(list1: LinkedList, list2: LinkedList) -> LinkedList:
    l1 = list1.head
    l2 = list2.head
    res_list = LinkedList()
    carry = 0

    while l1 is not None or l2 is not None:
        x = l1.data if l1 else 0
        y = l2.data if l2 else 0

        sum = carry + x + y

        res_list.add_last(Node(sum % 10))

        carry = carry // 10

        l1 = l1.next_node if l1.next_node else l1
        l2 = l2.next_node if l2.next_node else l2

    if carry > 0:
        res_list.add_last(Node(carry))
    
    return res_list
```

Comment: You don't advance from the next node, so that you never reach the `None` at the end. The last two lines in the `while` loop should be `lx = lx.next_node if lx else lx` or perhaps `if lx: lx = lx.next_node`.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that:

```
l1 = l1.next_node if l1.next_node else l1
l2 = l2.next_node if l2.next_node else l2
```

Is wrong.

That condition:

```
if l1.next_node
```

Won't assign `None` to l1/l2

You can drop the `if l1.next_node else l1`